# X509Certificate2 Access to a Private key into a security token

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, x509certificate2

I must use a certificate stored in a Security token. I can access it from the windows certificate store, but the device has a password, so is displayed a pop-up with a input field.

This is the code who I use for load the certificate:

```
static X509Certificate2 BuscarCertificado
    (StoreLocation location, StoreName name, 
    X509FindType findType, string findValue)
{
    X509Store store = new X509Store(name, location);
    try{
        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

        X509Certificate2Collection col = store.Certificates.Find
            (findType, findValue, true);

        return col[0];
    }
    finally { store.Close(); }
}
```

The device is a ACS CryptoMate64 0.

Is possible send the password in the code for not display this message?

Thanks for any help

Comment: no, it is not possible.

Comment: @CryptoGuy that is an interesting theory but can you prove it?

Comment: Please, ignore my comment. Pepo's code should work for you. Though, it will require to store PIN somewhere in the code (not recommended)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have ACS CryptoMate64 0. But this code works with Siemens CardOS v4.3B (drivers CardOS API v5.2 build 15). You will have to check if it works for you too.

```
using System.Security;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

namespace SignWithToken
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // ------ select certificate for signing ---------
            // open store
            X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
            store.Open(OpenFlags.MaxAllowed);

            // find cert by thumbprint
            var foundCerts = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "44 df b8 96 73 55 e4 e2 56 3a c0 a2 e0 66 8e 52 8a 3a 4a f4", true);

            if (foundCerts.Count == 0)
                return;

            var certForSigning = foundCerts[0];
            store.Close();

            // -------- prepare private key with password --------
            // prepare password
            var pass = new SecureString();
            for(var i=0;i<8;i++)
                pass.AppendChar('1');

            // take private key
            var privateKey = certForSigning.PrivateKey as RSACryptoServiceProvider;

            // make new CSP parameters based on parameters from current private key but throw in password
            CspParameters cspParameters = new CspParameters(privateKey.CspKeyContainerInfo.ProviderType,
                privateKey.CspKeyContainerInfo.ProviderName,
                privateKey.CspKeyContainerInfo.KeyContainerName,
                null,
                pass);

            // make RSA crypto provider based on given CSP parameters
            var rsaCsp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParameters);

            // set modified RSA crypto provider back
            certForSigning.PrivateKey = rsaCsp;

            // ---- Sign -----
            // prepare content to be signed
            ContentInfo content = new ContentInfo(new byte[] {0x01, 0x02, 0x03});
            SignedCms cms = new SignedCms(content);

            // prepare CMS signer 
            CmsSigner signer = new CmsSigner(certForSigning);

            // sign to PKCS#7
            cms.ComputeSignature(signer);

            // get encoded PKCS#7 value
            var result = cms.Encode();

            // ------ Verify signature ------
            SignedCms cmsToVerify = new SignedCms();
            // decode signed PKCS#7
            cmsToVerify.Decode(result);

            // check signature of PKCS#7
            cmsToVerify.CheckSignature(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your code do not work for my eToken Pro. It throws an exception: Exception calling "Main" with "1" argument(s): "The public key of the certificate does not match the value specified." at this line: certForSigning.PrivateKey = rsaCsp;

Comment: Does eToken Pro have CSP or a minidriver? Siemens 5.2 has a minidriver. But Siemens CardOS API v3.2 had a CSP. I had to add this to make it work `cspParameters.KeyNumber = privateKey.CspKeyContainerInfo.KeyNumber;
cspParameters.Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseExistingKey;` after cspParameters initialization.

Comment: eToken uses CSP, not minidriver.

Comment: Soo does it work if you set KeyNumber and Flags in cspParameters? I have only Siemens CardOS ...

Comment: I'm glad. But the additional properties should be set only if it is a CSP. With minidriver it just stops working suddenly.

Comment: This code is generating 'System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Access is denied.' while assigning the new PrivateKey in this line certForSigning.PrivateKey = rsaCsp;  Any help on what permission are required?

Comment: @ShashiJeevanM.P. I don't know what permissions are exactly needed. I would try privileged access (i.e. run as administrator).

Comment: @pepo Thank you for responding. I have tried running that as using cmd with administrator privileges. I did not work. This error is in the line where PrivateKey is being reassigned. Can I recreate X509Certificate2 object using a cloning approach? If yes, what is the correct approach to cloning that?